# call function when routing from a scene to another one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md) and this is my routing piece of code:

```
<Router navigationBarStyle={navBar} sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 53}}>
  <Scene key="main">       
    <Scene
      key="firstPage"  
      component={FirstPage}
      initial
    />

    <Scene 
      key="secondPage"
      component={SecondPage}
    />
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

This is a part of `FirstPage` component:

```
class FirstPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("constructor");
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("COMPONENT WILL MOUNT");
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("COMPONENT DID MOUNT");
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log("COMPONENT WILL RECEIVE PROPS");
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    console.log("SHOULD COMPONENT UPDATE")
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("COMPONENT DID UPDATE");
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log("COMPONENT WILL UNMOUNT");
  }
}
```

Once I open my app `FirstPage` component is loaded and I get this by `console.log`s:

```
COMPONENT WILL MOUNT
COMPONENT DID MOUNT
SHOULD COMPONENT UPDATE
```

When I click a button that sends me to `secondPage` key, loading SecondPage, component console.logs give me this:

```
COMPONENT WILL RECEIVE PROPS
SHOULD COMPONENT UPDATE
```

Until here, it's all Ok. What I'd like to have is to be able to trigger a function whenever I go back from `SecondPage` to `FirstPage`.
When I go back to the `FirstPage`, the constructor, componentWillMount, componentDidMount etc... aren't triggered.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a bit of an antipattern and also it might not suit your setup if you do not want to include a state container, but a suggestion would be to bind your app to a reducer that listens to changes in the current scene. For instance, with redux, you can easily do that by following the example in the [docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#reduxflux).

Then, the reducer will be triggered everytime the app's scene changes, and with that information I think you can apply any custom logic. You should not do that in the reducer (that is where the antipattern bit is), but what you can do is pass that value to your component and observe the `prop` in `componentWillReceiveProps` or any other appropriate lifecycle method. By comparing `nextProps` with your current `props`, you can infer what the user did.

This is a bit hacky, but it might do the job.